# Speeding up windows 7 aero animations

Tags: windows-7, aero

I am looking for a way to change the duration of Win7 aero animations

Animation examples:

- Minimize/Maximize window
- Show context menu and menu items (right click etc)
- Peed desktop from right-bottom corner (done it before, can't find it now)

To sum up: I want to shorten the duration of the above events

Comment: Mind the downvoter explain why?

Comment: Did the methods specified in my answer help you speed up Windows 7 Aero animations?

Answer (score 2):

### How to Speed up the Menu Show Delay Time in Windows 7:

1. Open the Start Menu, then type `regedit` in the search box and press
   `Enter`.
2. In regedit, navigate to the location below:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
   ```
3. In the right pane of the `Desktop` key, right click on `MenuShowDelay` and click on `Modify`.
4. Type in a number between `0` to `4000` (`400` is default) for how many milliseconds you want the Menu to wait before it opens.

   **Note:** The lower the number, the faster the response time. If you use an entry of `0`, there is no menu display delay. However it is not recommended to use `0` since the menus may be hard to navigate through at that speed. `20` is a good number to use.
5. Close regedit.
6. Log off and log on, or restart the computer to apply the changes.

### How to Change the Mouse Hover Time before Pop-up Displays in Windows 7:

1. Open the Start Menu, then type `regedit` in the search box and press
   `Enter`. If prompted by UAC, then click on `Yes`.
2. In regedit, navigate to the location below:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse
   ```
3. In the right pane, right click `MouseHoverTime` and click on `Modify`.
4. Type in a number between `0` to `4000` (`400` is default) for
   how many milliseconds, and click on `OK`.

   **Note:** The lower the number, the faster the response time. If you use an entry of   `0`, there is no delay before the tooltip opens.
5. Close regedit.
6. Log off and log on, or restart the computer to apply the changes.

---

Guide with screenshots and alternative methods on sevenforums.com:

- [How to Speed up the Menu Show Delay Time in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/731-menu-show-delay-time.html)
- [How to Change the Mouse Hover Time before Pop-up Displays in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1884-mouse-hover-time-change.html)

Comment: This does not answer how to speed up the animations of restore and open new window

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want (you asked about speeding, this is about turning off), but under Control Panel -> Performance -> Advanced -> Appearance and performance you can turn off the animation for minimize/maximize.

(I have turned it off because there is (on all machines I've ever seen) a short flicker a moment before the window reaches its full size (or just when it begins to shrink). It's like the animation is stumbling over something.)